# Automatic user signature in SQL

Tags: sql, create-table

Trying to add the user name to a table, but I get dbo as user name

```
CREATE TABLE username
(
ID int,
Date datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Signatur varchar(200) default CURRENT_USER,
Comment varchar(255),

);
```

AND THEN

```
INSERT INTO username
(Comment)
VALUES
('Just some text');

SELECT * FROM username
ORDER BY Date desc;
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txaXX.png)

When I replace CURRENT_USER with SYSTEM_USER or SUSER_SNAME() I get the user name DESKTOP-0DM0L90\jokr1

How do I get only **jokr1** as user name?

Comment: The original username is what you probably should be using.  The reason for this is that there could be a `jokr1` in another domain.  Following your advice, both users would collide, when in fact they should not.

Comment: Or, more likely, localhost\administrator vs domain\administrator.  I'd store the full username then split out the domain when you present it, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The full username is domain\user; so that's what all of the user/suser etc. commands give you.  You can use standard string manipulation techniques to get just one part of the string.

```
CREATE TABLE username
(
ID int,
Date datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
Signatur varchar(200) default right(SYSTEM_USER,len(SYSTEM_USER)-charindex('\',SYSTEM_USER)),
Comment varchar(255),

);
```

If you ever want to identify the 'user' associated with this, I would recommend storing the SID via:

```
SELECT SUSER_SID(system_user)
```